# Mysql issue in subquery

Tags: mysql, select, group-by, subquery, left-join

I have two mysql tables named `item` and `stock`.

```
select * from stock;
+----------+----------+-------+---------+-------------------+---------------+
| stock_id | qty_type | qty   | item_id | stock_location_id | stock_type_id |
+----------+----------+-------+---------+-------------------+---------------+
|       48 | v        | 44.00 |       1 |                 1 |             1 |
|       49 | v        |  8.00 |     263 |                 1 |             1 |
|       50 | a        |  6.00 |       1 |                 1 |             1 |
|       51 | a        |  4.00 |     263 |                 1 |             1 |
|       56 | a        | 21.00 |       1 |                 1 |             1 |
|       57 | a        | 57.00 |     263 |                 1 |             1 |
|       58 | a        |  6.00 |     264 |                 1 |             1 |
|       59 | a        | 19.00 |     301 |                 1 |             1 |
+----------+----------+-------+---------+-------------------+---------------+
```

Now I want to get all the items from `item` table along with all available `qty` from stock table.

This is how I tried it. But I couldn't get correct qty from stock table.

```
SELECT i.item_id
     , i.item_name
     , i.item_code
     , i.sku
     , i.min_qty 
     , i.max_qty   
     , sum(current_stock) as stock
  FROM item i 
      LEFT JOIN (
         SELECT item_id, qty_type, COALESCE(SUM(qty),0) AS current_stock 
           FROM stock 
       GROUP BY item_id
                ) s USING(item_id)
  WHERE s.qty_type = 'a';
```

Result from above query

```
+---------+------------------+-----------+------------+---------+---------+-------+
| item_id | item_name        | item_code | sku        | min_qty | max_qty | stock |
+---------+------------------+-----------+------------+---------+---------+-------+
|     264 | HONE CLIP RUBER  | MM-00264  | NOOR-00264 |      10 |      20 | 25.00 |
+---------+------------------+-----------+------------+---------+---------+-------+
1 row in set (0.001 sec)
```

You can see, I can't get all item records and that stock value also wrong with my query.

Can I know what I did wrong in my query?

Comment: Can you tell us is your idea to group again by i.item_id ?

Comment: Please update with item table definition too. Your sub query select item_id, qty_type but only item_id in group by, this is not correct.

Comment: I can't get all item records - 'If you use an aggregate function in a statement containing no GROUP BY clause' , https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html -

Comment: Hi @ugsgknt, you are not answering question or comments that people asked or commented. You had LIMIT 10 in your code that you do not need (it looks that way....). Your explanation is not good and after some edits from your side and with help of others it is still not so good. Also, there is a way to ask a question, if you try to find it how you will see there is a great explanation here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the condition `qty_type = 'a'` inside the subquery and use `COALESCE()` in the main query so that you get 0 for items that do not match the join:

```
SELECT i.*,   
       COALESCE(s.current_stock, 0) AS stock
FROM item i 
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT item_id, SUM(qty) AS current_stock 
  FROM stock
  WHERE qty_type = 'a' 
  GROUP BY item_id
) s USING(item_id);
```

The aggregation is needed only in the subquery.

Comment: So the LIMIT 10 is not needed ?

Comment: @VBoka what is LIMIT 10? I don't see it anywhere in the question.

Comment: Hi @forpas, click on the "edited 3 hours ago" above your icon at the end of the question and you will see why I asked.. It was in the code in the original question it is then changed....

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
SELECT i.item_id
     , i.item_name
     , i.item_code
     , i.sku
     , i.min_qty 
     , i.max_qty   
     , current_stock as stock
FROM item i 
LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT item_id, SUM(qty) AS current_stock 
        FROM stock 
        WHERE qty_type = 'a'
        GROUP BY item_id
                
    ) s USING(item_id);
```

Comment: You better update your question with your expectation. Not sure how u want to sum the total. Check the fiddle for subquery group by:
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b40a38545396ab521fb0664ae7ef400d